# Magento 2 - How to add custom block/template to transactional mail?

Tags: magento2, template, transactional-mail

In order confirmation email I want to **add custom block/template (phtml file)**. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 9):

We can do like this:

```
{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='Vendor_Module::email/custom.phtml'}}
```

See more here: `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/shipment_new.html`

Comment: Thanks, Dude your reference save my time.

Comment: What do you mean see more in shipment_new?

Comment: Where can I add the custom.phtml in my custom module?