# Pass array of data from email template to phtml in Magento 2.2.5

Tags: email, email-templates, magento-2.2.5

In magento 2.2.5, I need to pass data from mail template to phtml file. I did this using [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182163/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-block-template-to-transactional-mail). But I cannot pass array of data in it. only `text` it is accepting.

I am getting this error:

> Error filtering template: Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /root/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Filter.php on line 703

Comment: Please update your question so that we can check what you did for this.

Comment: check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/215374/55928) answer, maybe it helps

Comment: See my answer in this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295319/m2-how-to-print-array-values-in-custom-html-email-template-by-looping